# Como fazer meu conteúdo ficar atrás do meu popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

Sempre que clico no meu botão de exibir o popup, o meu conteúdo "desce". Como faço para que o popup fique acima do conteúdo?

```css
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.container2{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.btn2{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  background-color: #e91e63;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cover2{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:none;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index:999; 
} 
.popup2{
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
} 

p{
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  
}

.options2{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 
}

#close2{
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
 line-height:25px;
 font-size:25px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:2px solid;
 color: #ef2350;
 float:right;
 cursor:pointer;
} 

a{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 0px;
}  

#c a:first-child{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background-color:#2ecc71;
} 

#d a:last-child{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container2">
  <button class="btn2">alert message</button>
  <div class="popup2">
  <span id="close2">&times;</span>
   <p>Do You want to Delete??</p>
   <div class="options2">
    <div id="c"><a href="" id="cancela">cancel</a></div>
    <div id="d"><a href="" id="deleta">delete</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="cover2">
  
 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn2').on('click',function(){
    $('.cover2').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.popup2').fadeIn('slow');
   });
   $('.popup2').on('click',function(){
    if($(event.target).is('#close2')){
     $('.cover2').fadeOut('slow');
     $('.popup2').fadeOut('slow'); 
    } 
   });
   $('.cover2').on('click',function(){
    $('.cover2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.popup2').fadeOut('slow');
   });
   $('#cancela').on('click',function(){
    alert('Cancelado !');
   });
   $('#deleta').on('click',function(){
    alert('Deletado !');
   });
  });
 </script>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

É só mudar o `position:absolute;` para `position:fixed;`, assim a classe `.cover2` que é o seu modal ocupará toda a tela

***Segue o código modificado***

```css
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.container2{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.btn2{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  background-color: #e91e63;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cover2{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:none;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index:999; 
} 
.popup2{
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
} 

p{
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  
}

.options2{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 
}

#close2{
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
 line-height:25px;
 font-size:25px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:2px solid;
 color: #ef2350;
 float:right;
 cursor:pointer;
} 

a{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 0px;
}  

#c a:first-child{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background-color:#2ecc71;
} 

#d a:last-child{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container2">
  <button class="btn2">alert message</button>
  <div class="popup2">
  <span id="close2">&times;</span>
   <p>Do You want to Delete??</p>
   <div class="options2">
    <div id="c"><a href="" id="cancela">cancel</a></div>
    <div id="d"><a href="" id="deleta">delete</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="cover2">
  
 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn2').on('click',function(){
    $('.cover2').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.popup2').fadeIn('slow');
   });
   $('.popup2').on('click',function(){
    if($(event.target).is('#close2')){
     $('.cover2').fadeOut('slow');
     $('.popup2').fadeOut('slow'); 
    } 
   });
   $('.cover2').on('click',function(){
    $('.cover2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.popup2').fadeOut('slow');
   });
   $('#cancela').on('click',function(){
    alert('Cancelado !');
   });
   $('#deleta').on('click',function(){
    alert('Deletado !');
   });
  });
 </script>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</body>
</html>
```